# How to remove email+messaging data from my phone

Tags: email, storage, messaging

My email+messaging data is showing above 250 MB in Storage sense. I couldn't find any way to clean up the data. Is there any way? Deleting the messages from the email client doesn't affecting the data size.

Comment: Are you considering the SMS messages sent/received too? This calculation on storage sense is the sum of email + SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

In your email account settings you can choose for how long you want to keep your mails on your device. Change that to a lower value to get back some space.
When you delete your mails make sure you also clear the deleted mails folder. Also, a single mail might be too small to be noticed by storage sense.

Comment: I cannot find any option for that in email account settings in my Lumia. I have 4 email clients added to my Phone including Outlook.

Comment: @PraisonDaniGeorge In the mail app's settings, tap on "sync settings" and find the "Download email from" option.

Comment: But that option is only for getting the mails right? I want to remove them. But I couldn't find any options to remove those. @Thomas From where could I choose for how long to keep mails in the device?

Comment: If you set the duration like Indrek said older mails will be removed from your phone automatically.

Comment: I already set to the lowest possible number of days, but still showing more than 250 MB data. Is they including the data of People app in email+messaging in Storage Sense?

Comment: The People hub shouldn't have a big impact. Is it possible that you received a large attachment recently? Have you tried clearing the temporary data and doing a softreset?